# Oracle ODBC - missing drivers?

Tags: oracle, odbc, driver

I installed

ODAC 11.2 Release 3 and Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio (11.2.0.2.1)

from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/utilsoft-086879.html

but i still do not see Oracle driver in the ODBC Manager... please help.

i checked the ODBC Drivers in the Registry, and only found SQL there... maybe i downloaded the wrong thing? someone please point me in the right direction.

Comment: What version of Windows are you using and is it 32- or 64-bit?  There are separate 32- and 64-bit ODBC Driver Managers.  If you're installing the 32-bit version of the ODBC driver on a 64-bit platform, that can cause confusion.

Comment: Yes, I was going to mention what Justin mentioned. See this: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/942976. The 32-bit version of the Odbcad32.exe file is located in the %systemdrive%\Windows\SysWoW64 folder. The 64-bit version of the Odbcad32.exe file is located in the %systemdrive%\Windows\System32 folder.

Answer (score 17):

Call "c:\windows\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe" from the start/run box or from the command prompt, so 
the drivers are more likely to appear. I´ve been through similar problems with Oracle Instant Client (basic and ODBC) 32-bit driver not appearing at the ODBC Admin Window. I was able to configure a Data Source to Oracle 11g Express by calling "c:\windows\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe" this way.

Regards.

Comment: Since the operation system is 64-bit version, the default version of ODBC Data Source Administrator is 64-bit on the control panel and only list 64-bit version of drivers can be listed. To enumerate all 32-bit drivers such as Access, you can run the ODBC Data Source Administrator with 32-bit version which allocates at C:\Windows\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe by default.

Comment: I've been mucking around with this on and off for days, this worked instantly. Thanks so much for posting.

Answer (score 1):

I can't access the page you referenced to read about it, but to install the Oracle ODBC driver you can install the Oracle Instant Client. [This page](http://www.dbatoolz.com/t/installing-oracle-instantclient-basic-and-instantclient-sqlplus-on-win32.html) gives some good instructions on how to do it. Once the instant client is installed, the Oracle ODBC driver should show in the ODBC Manager. Note that you do not need a full client install to use the ODBC driver.

Comment: That page was really helpful. Thank you for the link! +1

Answer (score 0):

Run `cmd` with elevated privileges to install `odbc_install.exe`.